# How change Ant design Tooltip width

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, antd

I want to change the width of the tooltip, but I can't.
How do I do this?

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import {Tooltip} from "antd";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

export interface Props {
  tooltipeText: string
}

const hintWithTooltipeStyle = {
  position: 'relative' as 'relative',
  left: 5,
  top: 1
};


const HintWithTooltipe: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  tooltipeText
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <span style={hintWithTooltipeStyle}>
      <Tooltip placement="rightTop" title={tooltipeText} style={{width: 700, maxWidth: '500px !important'}}>
        <Button>Ant design</Button>
      </Tooltip>
    </span>
  );
};

export default HintWithTooltipe;
```

Inline styles don't work.
No styles work at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [antd Tooltip](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/) can be adapted by overriding values in css class `.ant-tooltip-inner`.

```css
.ant-tooltip-inner {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Here is a working [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-gould-l3b5t) have a look at the `index.css` file for changes.

Comment: with styled components, this is not working https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-monad-urol3
can you explain ?

Comment: @AjitTStephen Tooltip is created at the root of the DOM, styled-components will only apply the style to the components below it.

Comment: This changes globally right. I think this is not a good practice. @zerocewl

Answer (score 18):

You can do it like this without css class:

```html
<Tooltip placement="rightTop" title={tooltipeText} overlayStyle={{maxWidth: '500px'}}>
     <Button>Ant design</Button>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you could access **overlayInnerStyle** property from [Tooltip](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/).

```
<Tooltip overlayInnerStyle={{width: '250px'}} title={`tootltip text`}>
  Info Text
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should  use `min-width` for changing inside border

```
overlayStyle={{ maxWidth: '260px' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple approach

```
<Tooltip
              placement="top"
              title={pageNumberInfo}
              overlayClassName="pageNumberInfo"
            >
              <FaCircleInfo />
            </Tooltip>
```

in this way your class name will be added to the tooltip and you can style that by using

```
.pageNumberInfo .ant-tooltip-arrow::before {
    background: white; /* for the tooltip arrow */
}
.pageNumberInfo .ant-tooltip-inner {
    background-color: white;
}
```

I will not recommend to apply styling using

```
.ant-tooltip-inner {
    /*css styles*/
}
```

it will change the style of all tooltips on your current page,
and I am not a fan of inline styling as that is not considered as best practice